# A function $F:\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \rm numerators$

Tags: number-theory

Is it possible to express explicitly a function that takes as its input a rational number and outputs the numerator (or denominator) of that number)?

Edit: I want something that will give me, for example, f(.5)=1 or f(1/2)=1 (but since this is a single valued function we can't know beforehand what is in the numerator and denominator of a number in the domain).

Edit: To further clarify what I mean, let me give a naive non-example:
y=7x is a function that will take (5/7) to 5. However this function will not output the numerator of every rational. I seek a function that will do this. I am not asking the function to recognize (at least to begin with) what the numerator or denominator of the fraction is. The function can't simply be "given a rational $x,$ convert $x$ to fraction form in lowest form and read off the numerator.

Comment: What do you mean by "express explicitly"? As far as I'm concerned, modulo the lowest-terms and sign trivialities mentioned below, you've already expressed it.

Comment: Maybe your question is how to transform a decimal expression that you know corresponds to a rational number into the corresponding quotient (from which one can immediately discern the numerator, of course). Is this what you are asking?

Comment: If a computer or calculator does this calculation, starting with a decimal, it may not be able to discern the numerator from the denominator (I know it can but lets say it can't). In this case I want to output the numerator without any human input. So at no point in time am I allowed to simply look at the fraction and say what the numerator is....this means that any operation being performed on the fraction cannot make use of what the numerator or demoninator is.

Comment: Yet another casualty of the difference between the mathematical definition of function (a certain kind of subset of a Cartesian product) and the naive intuitive interpretation of function (a specified sequence of arithmetic operations).

Comment: @illysian: Could it be that what you are *actually* asking is related to "I have a decimal numeral. I would like to find a rational number with relatively small denominator that is very close to the real number value of my numeral?" If so, then look up "continued fractions".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a *polynomial* function with that property? No: it has to take the value $1$ infinitely often, and if a polynomial takes a value infinitely often, the polynomial must be the constant function.

**Proof:** Suppose there are infintiely many $\xi$ such that $f(\xi) = a$. Then every $\xi$ is a root of the polynomial $g(x) = f(x) - a$. However, nonzero polynomials can only have finitely many roots: therefore $g(x) = 0$, and thus $f(x) = a$ is the constant polynomial.

Is there a *rational* function with that property? No: again, taking the value $1$ infinitely often implies that the rational function would have to be constant.

Is there a *function*? Yes: "f(x) = the numerator of $x$ when written in lowest terms" defines it.

Another short expression of this function is "$f(p/q) = p$ whenever $p,q$ is in lowest terms". Another one in a similar vein is:

$$ f\left(\frac{p}{q} \right) = \operatorname{sgn}(q) \frac{p}{|\gcd(p,q)|} $$

where $p$ ranges over all integers and $q$ ranges over all nonzero integers, with no joint condition on the variables.

Is there an algorithm that can obtain the numerator of a rational function, using only addition, subtraction, multiplication, equality testing, and the numbers $0$ and $1$? Yes: in pseudocode

```
def numerator(q):
    x = 1
    loop forever:
        spawn new thread to check is_integer(q*x)
            return q*x when the first thread answers "yes"
        x = x + 1

def is_integer(q):
    spawn new thread to check is_natural(q)
        if this thread ever answers "yes", then return "yes"
    execute is_natural(-q)
        if this ever answers "yes", then return "yes"

def is_natural(q):
    x = 0
    loop forever:
        if q = x then return "yes"
        x = x + 1
```

This, however, assumes that you're given *exact* arithmetic; no algorithm can possibly work, of course, if you're only given an approximation to the true value.

Just to emphasize, all three of the functions I list above are the ***same*** mathematical function; I just wrote it in three different ways.

Comment: If you're a picky computer scientist, then you should be able to insert the synchronization to ensure all of the threads run at the same rate, so that the algorithm computes the right answer without any race conditions.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, but you need to make sure the function is well defined by declaring one must write $\frac ab $ in lowest terms, i.e. $\gcd(a,b)=1$, and say $a\in\Bbb Z,b\in\Bbb N^*$. Else we may write elements in various ways, $(-2)/1,2/(-1),4/(-2)$ yielding an ill-defined function.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that wouldn't even be a function, because $1/2 = 2/4$, but $f(1/2) = 1$ and $f(2/4) = 2$. If we require that $p/q$ be a reduced fraction, then we lose that problem and the function would just be $f(p/q) = p$.

Comment: You also need to make sure the signs match.

Comment: Good point. I didn't think of that. We could just say that if p/q is negative, then make p the negative one, right?

Comment: Yes, you can specify that the negative sign goes in the numerator (or in the denominator, if you prefer).  That removes the ambiguity and makes it a function.